# How to pass the device token from AppDelegate to UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, devicetoken

Hi in my application I'm fetching the device token and I'm passing to my server to send the notification now I want to send the individual notification for the i need to fetch the device token form my `UIViewController` Please tell is there any possibilities fetching the device token form the `Appdelegate` or from the `UIViewController`

My code for fetching the device token in `Appdelegate`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone)];
     return YES;
}
```

Device Token.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
   {
      const char* data = [deviceToken bytes];
      NSMutableString * token = [NSMutableString string];

    for (int i = 0; i < [deviceToken length]; i++) {
       [token appendFormat:@"%02.2hhX", data[i]];
    }

   NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"url?token=%@",token];

   NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
   NSLog(@"token %@",urlString);


   NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   NSLog(@"request %@ ",urlRequest);
   NSData *urlData;
   NSURLResponse *response;
   urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
   NSLog(@"data %@",urlData);

  }
```

I have used the to get the device token please tell me how to pass the device token to my `UIViewController` or how to fetch the device token from my `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `NSUserDefaults` to store the objects(values), you can access it anywhere.

**AppDelegate (setValue) :**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: token forKey:@"deviceID"];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
}
```

**UIViewController (getValue) :**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"deviceID"];
```

Comment: please tell me in appdelegate where i have use the nsuserdefault in which method i have to declare

Comment: Register at `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`

Comment: i have used the above code im facing two problems one its showing error on NSuserdefault to replace with Nsuserdefaults and after replacing its showing warining in standards

Comment: in standards its showing as aclass method +standarddefault not found (return type defaults toid)

Comment: Sorry, I just typed . So its typo mistake . Check now

Comment: in UIViewController viewdidload i have give the ur code please tell me how to know wheather its passing the value or not

Comment: It doesn't pass. it always holds the value, even you quit the App as well .
NSLog (@"deviceId %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"deviceID"];

Comment: ok now how can i display the device token in my uilabel view or nslog to know its holding the value

Comment: Check this in `-(void)viewDidLoad{
NSLog (@"deviceId %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"deviceID"]; 
}`

Comment: `myLabel.text =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"deviceID"];`

Answer (score 4):

In AppDelegate.m class:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);

    NSString *device = [deviceToken description];
    device = [device stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    device = [device stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"My device is: %@", device);

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:device forKey:@"MyAppDeviceToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

In ViewController class, inside viewDidLoad method:

```
[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *deviceToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyAppDeviceToken"];
NSLog(@"device token in controller: %@ ", deviceToken);
```

This is working perfectly in my device. Happy Coding !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this coding in your view did load

```
NSString* deviceId = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
deviceId = [deviceId stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@",deviceId);
```

Comment: OP doesn't need new deviceId, he's already getting one from remote notification delegate. Btw, `identifierForVendor` is app vendor specific, it'll change once all apps from the same vendor will get removed from the device.

Answer (score 0):

Declare and define below methods in your delegate file,

```
#pragma mark - Get / Set Device Token
+ (void)setDeviceToken:(NSString *)token {
    if(token) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"DeviceToken"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}

+ (NSString *)getDeviceToken {
    NSString *token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DeviceToken"];
    if(token) {
        return token;
    }
    return @"";
}
```

In `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken` method
call, `[AppDelegate setDeviceToken:token];` once you get the token and

Now in project, in any view controller, you can call `NSString *token = [AppDelegate getDeviceToken];` to get saved token, here note that, we call it with `AppDelegate` its name of your delegate file, and we call it with the class name, as we make a class method to set and get a token.

At the time of getting you can check for availability of saved token

```
NSString *token = [AppDelegate getDeviceToken];
if(token.length) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: why do you need to check for everyTime ` if(token) ` etc .  `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` this could call only if there is a tokenId.

Comment: Yes, that's true in this case, but I am not really took any risk with my app and my code, if in case, I'll get nil, my app won't get crash! This is my practice to check validity of object before doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can get appDelegate instance in any view contoller and fetch value from that instance like -

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```